# How do I dismiss the console?

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just got to the part where I can use my hands, and the first thing I did was open a chest. I couldn't work out how to close it, so started pressing buttons to see what worked. I've now opened the dev console, and can't get rid of it.

Comment: If anyone's coming here for help closing a chest menu: use Tab. (This is a really unintuitive UX design choice.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways to close the console:

- Use the tilde key (<kbd>`</kbd> / <kbd>~</kbd> on Qwerty, <kbd>²</kbd> / <kbd>³</kbd> on Azerty) to toggle the console.
- Type the command `CloseMenu Console` to close the console if the key doesn't work.

Comment: They really should have added `exit` or `quit` as well.. even `help` would have been nice. First time I didn't know (I hit) the console key and couldn't get out :/

Comment: Two of the three commands you mention should be there...

Comment: I had to type `HideMenu Console` to close the console. I don't know if things have changed since '11, or one of my mods is interfering though.

Answer (score 2):

Hit the <kbd>`</kbd> again and the console should close. Depending on what language setting your keyboard has, it might also be <kbd>^</kbd> or <kbd>~</kbd> .

Answer (score -1):

on a spanish keyaboard it is the `|` symbol to the left of the `1` key, or right below the `ESC` key

Comment: This is really better suited as a comment than an entirely separate answer

Comment: well, I found myself in the same situation as the OP, and for me the correct answer is the one I posted, so why is it not an answer on its own right?